# Is there any better way to check the online status of IIS from client?

Tags: c#, .net, http, iis

We have the following setup:

Server:
Virtual server, Intel Xeon E5-2697v4 x 2, 32GB RAM, 4 processors, Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Edition, IIS 8.5

Client:
Windows 7 SP3, Celeron 2.4GHz, 4GB RAM, Chrome 41

There are 1 Server and 600 Clients running in working time.
Each of client is checking if the IIS is online by open a html page which is saved in IIS every 1-2 minutes and about 900 times one day one client.

The online check method is programmed by C#.NET Framework using WebRequest.GetResponse().

The online check method takes about 50ms usually, but sometime takes about 5000ms. The ratio of 50ms to 5000ms is 100:1.

Could someone tell me is there any better way to do the online check of IIS from client because the client cannot do anything when doing the online check and it's terrible when the online check takes 5000ms?

Thank you!

Comment: Use a `HEAD` or `CONNECT` instead of `GET`?

Comment: Why not use a single machine to check then broadcast to other client?

Comment: You have no control over windows operating system delays unless you set the priority of the task to a higher level.  Windows Task Swapping often gives delays like you are seeing.

Comment: "client cannot do anything when doing the online check" - that's just sound like a bad decision on your part... If you explain why did you do that it may help to find an answer?

Comment: @Geno Chen I think HEAD is a good idea. I will try it soon. Thanks. And I cannot use a single machine to check because the clients are in different area all over the country.

Comment: @XjAcKs Oh, OK. I'm thinking about something like a classroom :-)

Comment: @jdweng Can I bring the delays down if I set the priority of the IIS process to a higher level in Task Manager of Windows?

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov The online check method will be called when any task clicked by user  which need get data from IIS. So the task cannot continue unless get the result of online check.

Comment: @Geno Chen I tried to use HEAD instead of GET but the delay is increased...

Comment: @XjAcKs You may use some tools, for example Fiddler, to check the time cost of every progress (wait, connect, send, receive, etc.) of a network request for debugging.

Comment: @Geno Chen OK, I will try it. Thank you.